# Use Vmware VGA driver on Proxmox for KVM Windows Guests

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, drivers

I follow this tutorial (http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/using-vmware-vga-kvm-windows-guests) to use Vmware VGA with KVM Windows Guests.

The vmware vga driver is installed on Windows, but I can't select "vmvga" into Proxmox's interface. I can just choose "default", "Standard VGA" and "Cirrus Logic GD5446".

I tried command "kvm" and "qm" but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [a Proxmox forum post](http://forum.proxmox.com/threads/3927-Higher-resolution-for-KVM-guests-by-using-quot-vga-vmware-quot-e.g.-for-Ubuntu-Lucid) and [info on vmware vga setting in KVM](http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/kvm-77-released-std-vga-deprecated-improved-disk-performance): you might try editing your conf file for the machine, e.g. /etc/qemu-server/101.conf, and add a line

args: -vga vmware